# Capture Survey Response from an Email and store answers into a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html5, survey

Is there a way that we can create a survey in the Email and capture the customer responses in the Data Extension?

I'm looking for a solution for it, and found out that Surveys are no longer available in Content Builder, it can only be accessed on Classic Content.

Comment: Surveys/forms aren't supported in MOST email clients anymore.  The best you can do is provide a faux-form that either sends you to a cloudPage or if it's a like a "how many stars do we get 1-5" you could use ampscript to write that response into a data extension using an `InsertDATA` ampscript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomCallahan mentioned, HTML forms are not supported in all email clients. And even in the ones that it is supported, you will usually get a warning or other pop up from the email client warning you that this form is pushing information to an outside web page. Or the form displayed is not styled or displayed as you set it. For instance, Hotmail will display what is essentially a 'plain text' version of the form.

[image: Warning]

Basically using an HTML form inside an email is a terrible User Experience in the majority of email clients - regardless if supported or not.

[Support of HTML forms in email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/11/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/): (as of 2017 - most recent display of support I could find)
[image: Email Client Form Support]

My recoomendation is to either have the survey live on a Cloudpage or other website (survey monkey, etc.) or to have 1 question Yes or No response and have a cloud page that collects the button pushed and inserts into a DE.  E.g. have the answer parameter added on URL in href.  `<a href="https://yourURL.com?a=Yes">Yes</a>` Then just use RequestParameter() on the Cloudpage to collect the value and insert into the DE.

Comment: Thank you @gortoningtonfor the response.